# How to code a serverless AWS lambda function that will download a linux third party application using wget and then execute commands from that app?

Tags: python, node.js, linux, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I would like to use a serverless lambda that will execute commands from a tool called WSO2 API CTL as I would on linux cli. I am not sure of how to mimic the downloading and calling of the commands as if I were on a linux machine using either Nodejs or Python via the lambda?

I am okay with creating and setting up the lambda and even getting it in the right VPC so that the commands will reach an application on an EC2 instance but I am stuck at how to actually execute the linux commands using either Nodejs or Python and which one would be better, if any.

After adding the following I get an error trying to download:

os.system("curl -O [https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/assets/attachments/learn/api-controller/apictl-3.2.1-linux-x64.tar.gz"](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/assets/attachments/learn/api-controller/apictl-3.2.1-linux-x64.tar.gz%22))

Warning: Failed to create the file apictl-3.2.1-linux-x64.tar.gz: Read-only

Comment: Both languages have an operating system interface to run external programs, typically called `system`. After you download to `/tmp`, you may need to make your program executable via the equivalent of `chmod +x` and then execute `/tmp/myexe`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is no specific reason to download `apictl` during the initialisation of your Lambda. Therefore, I would propose to bundle it with your deployment package.

The advantage of this approach are:

1. Quicker initialisation
2. Less code in your Lambda

You could extend your CI/CD pipeline to download the application during build and then add it to your ZIP archive that you deploy.